# Linq - How to delete all colum in local database window phone?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

I have two table,for example,table A and table B.

i use linq to perform action,after finsh task I want to delete all row in table A (not delete database). I don't know how to delete all row in table A.

Comment: I meant I want to delete all data in table.

Comment: what kind of table, sqlite table? have you tried : `db.DeleteAll<tableA>();`

Answer (score 0):

If You have a table

```
[Table]
public class A
{
   ...
}
```

and database context dbDataContext

```
    public Table<A> a
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<A>();
        }
    }
```

then to delete all rows from table A

```
    public void DeleteSDetails()
    {
        using (Database.dbDataContext context = new Database.dbDataContext(Con_String))
        {
            IQueryable<Database.A> stQuery = from c in context.a select c;
            foreach (var value in stQuery)
            {
                context.a.DeleteOnSubmit(value);
            }
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```